# Merging changes in LINQ to SQL entities

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following code that updates the JobCard object returned from a strongly typed view.  However, calling `GetModifiedMembers` with the JobCard entity returns every property of JobCard, with `CurrentValue` and `OriginalValue` both set to the current value.

```
    public int Update(BusinessObjects.JobCard model)
    {
        Poynting.Installation.DataObjects.LinqToSql.JobCard entity = JobCardMapper.ToEntity(model);
        using (Database db = DataContextFactory.CreateContext())
        {
            try
            {
                //LinqToSql.JobCard origJobCard = db.JobCards.Single(jc => jc.JobID == model.InstallationDBNumber);
                db.JobCards.Attach(entity, true);
                db.SubmitChanges();
```

I suspect this is because we are using `Attach`, and not actually updating an attached entity.  As this update is called by an HttpPost action method, we can't keep the entity attached.  I'm guessing that if I don't attach the incoming entity, but instead use its values to update an attached JobCard entity (starting with the commented out line), my audit service will detect the correct changes.

My main question here is: Do I have to loop through each property of `entity` and set the corresponding property on `origJobCard`, or is there some sort of merge operation available to me somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've correctly identified your options here except for maybe one, which may or may not be attractive: along with the original entity that gets serialized (detached) during the http operation, you could send a clean copy/clone of the same entity which would remain unchanged and when the http operation is finished you'd pass both the dirty and clean detached entities to the [`Attach(TEntity, TEntity)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548972.aspx) method.

Looping through the properties and copying values from the detached entity to an attached entity (as you suggested) may actually be less work (but it's not very efficient, unless you cache `columnProperties` somewhere and avoid doing the search over and over).

Here's an example of the loop method:

```
List<PropertyInfo> columnProperties = typeof(Employee).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true).Any())
    .ToList();

Employee employee1 = new Employee() { VacationHours = 100 };
Employee employee2 = new Employee() { VacationHours = 10 };

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in columnProperties)
{
    object value = pi.GetValue(employee1, null);
    pi.SetValue(employee2, value, null);
}
```

As you can see, since your question is almost six months old, I'm mostly doing this for coding/answering practice.  Cheers!

**[Edit]**

[Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Projection&referringTitle=Home) might be another option.  Or Automapper plus a dedicated view-object like in [this answer and discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807221/using-linq-to-sql-classes-as-a-model-and-hiding-certain-fields/4807374#4807374).